# Is there whoami analog for Docker?

Tags: docker

It would be useful for me to get what user I logged in with the previous `docker login`. I didn't find anything like that in `docker help` but maybe there's something I don't know.

Is there anything like `whoami` in Docker command line client? For example, something like `docker whoami`. Maybe there's not official utility?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should contain login information and authentication tokens (while logged in).

For modern docker this can be found at: `~/.docker/config.json`
For older docker versions this is at: `~/.dockercfg`

Comment: OK, thanks! I think this is what I needed, so can do `cat ~/.dockercfg` to get the currect user.

Comment: BTW, in ubuntu 14.04 it's `~/.docker/config.json` file.

Comment: In MacOS it's `~/.docker/config.json`